# How can I reach the device in a LAN from both external and sub LAN?

Tags: networking, router, lan, samba, https

I have a device, the target device in the diagram, running a website providing service through HTTPS (and HTTP is necessary too for TLS certificate renewal) and also providing samba service for internal use.

The device is attached to the router A which is provided by the ISP to connect to the internet by optical fiber.

And all my other devices are attached to Router B as a sub LAN. Router B is connected to router A. I use router B to provide WiFi.

Both routers A and B are providing DHCP services.

[image]

I want to access the website on my Target Device both from the sub LAN managed by router B (②), and the devices in the internet (①), and access the samba provided by the target device from only the sub LAN (③).

How can I implement this?

I think I can configure the port forwarding on Router A to let the device with internet access the website (①), but I have no idea how I can make the target device reachable from the sub LAN (② and ③).

---

I know I can attach the target device to router B and configure the port forwarding on both Router A and B. But the problem is that my router B don't have enough LAN port for the target device and I don't want a wireless connection which is much slower than LAN cable since it is a server. So this is not currently an acceptable solution in my case.

---

I also know that I could set router B to AP mode (I am not sure whether this is the term I should use) that could merge the two LANs into one, and every device gets IP from router A's DHCP. But the router A only supports a limited number of devices and I have much more devices. So this is also not a good solution in my case.

---

**EDIT: my final solution**

Well, I haven't really solved this problem, but found a way to bypass the problem.

I found a device attached to Router B that I haven't used it for more than 1 year. So I removed the device and got a spare port for the Target Device.

Now, I just set the port forwarding for HTTP/HTTPS on both Router A and Router B and give the Target Device a fixed IP in DHCP settings on Router B. Then done. Everything works like expect.

Furthermore, I also have some internal domain name, but my Router B don't support a custom DNS record, so I just set them on Router A.

This is the diagram.

[image: solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, setting up the port forward on router A will make the server reachable from the Internet. Note that devices on your LAN will also be able to reach the server **via its public IP address** (assuming they have internet access).

Note: I assume the networks are `/24` with the subnet mask 255.255.255.0 and I'm using the terminology "server" instead of "target device".

**About the access via private IP (`192.168.1.4`)**: If the **current setup** is not working for LAN traffic, my guess is (additional causes are possible as well):

- either router B doesn't route the traffic to the server since it's a private IP trying to leave through the WAN port, you could check this e.g by using Wireshark (but be aware that there will be IP translation because of the NAT). A simpler way to do a part-way test would be to check if you can ping router A (`192.168.1.4`) from a client on the router A subnet  (`192.168.1.0/24`) and router B subnet (`192.168.10.0/24`), a failure to ping from subnet B (but not from subnet A) will mean most likely that the server can not be reached either.
- and/or that router A doesn't "know" what to do with packets for `192.168.10.0/24` and sends them via the default route/interface (to the internet). Meaning although the server receives incoming packets from the LAN it can not send them back. In this case, you must manually add a route to router A (if possible). Note as Tom Yan points out: Setting a route on the server to route `192.168.10.0/24` to `192.168.1.2` might work as well, depending on the configuration of router B (it needs to allow packets for `192.168.10.0/24` to come through the WAN port).

**An alternative setup/solution for access via private IP** (in my view the "best" solution by paying a few bucks for an additional network adapter thus getting reducing configuration/testing necessities) would be to add another network interface to the server and connect it to router B. This way it would get a second IP address from `192.168.10.0/24` that can be used for access from the LAN.

**Regarding your own solutions**, they might work without running into the problems you described:

Another alternative solution would be to buy a switch for router B, this would give you more LAN ports to support all your devices. Note, then you could even turn off the routing capabilities of router A, using it just as a modem (if possible through the settings), making router B your only router. Maybe it's even possible to use router B to connect to your ISP without using router A.

To set Router B to AP mode is actually the "best" solution (especially since you get rid of the double NAT and you don't need a second network adapter for the server), why exactly is the number of devices supported by router A limited? What about router A?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How could I know whether the router support adding a route? The Router A is HG8045Q made by HUAWEI.
About the number of devices, it only support 32 devices. Well, the HG8045Q is the router I will use actually. My current device is F660A which only support 10 devices. The ISP would send me a HG8045Q to increase the number, but that might be not enough in the future.

Comment: `my guess is that router A doesn't "know" what to do with packets for 192.168.10.0/24` That only occurs if NAT on router B is disabled though. Also, more ideally the route for `192.168.10.0/24` should be added on `Target Device` (or other LAN hosts in the "outer LAN") instead of `Router A`. (Certainly if you rely on DHCP, the best way to have it is to make the DHCP server on Router A to push the extra route to its clients.)

Comment: Another possibility is that Router B's firewall (statelessly) blocks all traffics with source (and / or destination) address in the [private IP blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses) from getting into LAN from WAN. Like {pf,opn}sense has a dedicated switch on its admin portal for this.

Comment: @Programus you should check the manual about adding a route but my guess is it doesn't (most "low end" consumer routers don't with the original firmware). Do you know the reason why it can't support more than 10/30 devices? Is it the maximum number of IPs for the DHCP? Please also check the updates to my answer.

Comment: @TomYan you are correct, adding the route to the target device might resolve the issue (however if router B blocks IPs for network 192.168.10.0/24 coming through the WAN port, this might not work as you point out in your second comment). I'm not sure what you mean by `That only occurs if NAT on router B is disabled though`. If NAT (and DHCP) would be disabled, there would be no need to route the packets since it all would be on the same subnet.

Comment: @TomYan Thank you for your advices, just like Albin said, my router may not support adding a route, I have read the manual but didn't find anything like add a route...

Comment: @Albin I am not sure, but I guess the reason of the limitation may be the DHCP or DNS or both. Because actually the network configuration I am using is Router B as AP mode, but I disabled the Router B's DHCP and DNS, and I am using the DHCP and DNS provided by dnsmasq on Target Device. But I find the soft DHCP and DNS is a little slow than the hard one on the router. Some devices would not be able to get IP address or have DNS problem if I used the Router B's DHCP & DNS.

Comment: @Programus note that I added an additional solution and did some further updates in my answer. Is the server (target device) connected to router B? If not how does the DHCP on the server reach the clients connected to router B? The information in your question doesn't show that. Note that you don't need a local DNS server if you don't resolve local domain names.

Comment: @Programus also I would suggest finding out what is technically causing a limit on clients there might be an easy solution or another option. It might be DHCP (a few things possible there), not sure how DNS could limit the number of clients.

Comment: @Albin Assuming Router B is a typical home router, by default it will (S)NAT traffics from the LAN by rewriting the source address (to `192.168.1.2` in this case), which means the replying traffics from target device will not even reach the "router part" of router A but will merely be switched / L2 forwarded back to router B directly. (No L3 forwarding / filtering would even be involved.) (The "original" traffics from the inner LAN will not reach the "router part" of router A either since the destination address is covered by the prefix route for `192.168.1.0/24` on router B)

Comment: @Albin I also think the reason of the limitation is DHCP. If so, is there any solution for this better than my current soft DHCP?

Comment: @TomYan Is there any way to verify your theory? The target device is running Linux system and I have root user. Maybe there is a way to check the packets? If I didn't misunderstand you, if your theory is verified, the 'add a route' solution would be helpless, isn't it?

Comment: You can always `tcpdump` or so on target device. It's not really a "theory" though, it's really just a "matter" of how your devices are configured (e.g. is SNAT enabled / is the subnet mask / prefix length correct, etc.). As I said, if your router B has SNAT enabled (which should be the case unless you disabled it), you shouldn't even need any additional route, which is why I think that the some firewall rules blocking traffics with private IP in their address fields from getting in from the WAN side is a more likely case.

Comment: If you see traffics source address being 192.168.1.2 and destination address being 192.168.1.4 AND *the other way round* on target device when you access it with a host from the inner LAN, then it more or less proved my theory (of the private IP blocking firewall rules). Btw I bet you can't reach / ping router A from an inner LAN host either (but able to reach the Internet)? (Actually DNS should be broken if you use router B as your DNS server if it turn use router A as its DNS server...)

Comment: @TomYan I agree there could be problems with home routers blocking the traffic to the server as well (I added this to my answer), good idea trying to ping router A from subnet B to test it.

Comment: @Programus if it's a limit of the DHCP and not the size of the subnet you can simply use your own DHCP instead or you could assign additional IPs manually. Assuming a "hidden firewall feature" doesn't block traffic outside of the DHCP range.

Comment: Thank you both! I will have a try this Saturday, and I will get back if I have any further questions.

Comment: @Programus after thinking about it, personally I would do the "alternative setup/solution" (additional network adapter), in my view it's the easiest to implement (and you probably have a USB network adapter laying around anyway - if not it's a good idea to have a spare one lying around for testing purposes so you might want to get one anyway). The other solutions might be fundamentally better (no double NAT etc.) but they probably come with higher configuration effort and you'll always have the option to implement them anyway. Thanks for your feedback, +1 for that! Curious how this plays out.

Comment: @Albin I updated my solution in the question. Almost the same as your buy a switch solution, but just removed a device I haven't used for more than 1 year to get the room for the Target Device. Thank you for your help and all alternatives. I believe others may be helped by your answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Avoid Double NAT

1. Your ISP provided modem/router should be set in bridge mode to avoid double NAT.
   [Putting Huawei ONT into Bridge Mode](https://forum.huawei.com/enterprise/en/huawei-ont-bridge-mode-introduction/thread/498679-100181)
2. Your Internal router/firewall should manage DHCP and control access to and from your LAN and the Internet.
3. Router/firewall setup is a broad topic and you will need to deal with some or all of NAT, reverse proxy, Access Control Lists (ACL), etc.
4. Roles can be split up between devices or multiple roles hosted on a single device.

Your basic layout would look more like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately the router from my ISP does not support bridge mode. 

Comment: I would be surprised.  You may need to ask them to set it from their end. Look at this though: https://forum.level1techs.com/t/hg8045h-how-to-get-this-to-bridge-to-my-main-router/89465/7

Comment: and this: https://forum.level1techs.com/uploads/default/original/3X/c/2/c28fd165482ec12bde7ee173f51ec337670ad0eb.png

Comment: It isn't something that is usually restricted by ISP's.

Comment: Well, I will try once I get the new router, at least my current one does not have such a setting. But I think the bridge mode is not the critical point in my case, I can use port forwarding instead, at least. In your solution, I have to get an additional switch... well, that's not so expensive though, but I still want to know whether there is a perfect solution without additional devices.

Comment: Oh, yes, maybe DMZ is another alternative of bridge mode, too.

Comment: @BlindSpots the OP already suggested avoiding double NAT but it's not possible since router A doesn't support enough devices and router B doesn't have enough Ethernet ports. Maybe you could edit your answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Programus DMZ is not the same as bridge mode. Normally DMZ is used to give access to devices from the WAN/internet (bypass certain FW restrictions that apply to the LAN). DMZ can also be used to avoid double NAT for access from the WAN, but this is not your problem (you try to access from the LAN). However DMZ might still be able to solve your problem, I haven't thought it through just yet.

Comment: @Albin yes, I was not convinced given the information I found online.  Did you find something different?

Comment: @BlindSpots not really sure what you mean by "I was not convinced given the information I found online." Could you elaborate? I was referring to your headline which points out a solution, that is dismissed by the OP.

Comment: In researching the HW it appears that it may be able to be set to Bridge mode.